# Exact Calculation of Infinite Monkeys Problem

Tags: probability

If I'm wondering if there is a nice closed for expression for the probability that $N$ monkeys will type out a text of length $\ell$ in a time $t$, where the monkeys type characters at a rate $r$, and we suppose our alphabet has $k$ characters in it.

I think the expectation of this problem works out nicely, but I think expectations are often easier to computer than probabilities. The problem here is that the event of the first $\ell$ characters not being the text is not independent from the event of the $2^{nd}$ to the $\ell+1^{th}$ characters being the text.

If there isn't a good closed form solution, what's the best approximation?

Comment: The problem is that you'd have three separate cases to cover when the number of letters typed is less than $\ell$, equal to $\ell$ and greater than $\ell$.  If we ignore the case when the number of letters typed is less than or equal to $\ell$, there may yet be an elegant solution.

Comment: This is a well-know problem with a good Poisson approximation: $$T\overset{d}\approx k+\exp(Nr^{-1}k^{-l})$$ for any reasonable (no overlapping) text and small rate of the exponential. For overlapping text you need to mulptiply the above rate by something less than $1:$ $1-k^{-1}$ at the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of letters typed will be $r\cdot t$. Suppose $\ell\le rt$. Then the number of places to put a string of $\ell$ letters in a string of $rt$ letters is $rt-\ell+1$. Given that we choose a certain spot for our $\ell$ letters the number of combinations where that happens is $k^{rt-\ell}$. Multiplying this number with $rt-\ell+1$ gives an upper bound for the desired probability:
$$
\frac{(rt-\ell+1)k^{rt-\ell}}{k^{rt}} = \frac{rt-\ell+1}{k^\ell}.
$$
Note that we counted some sequences multiple times, but removing those depends on the specific sequence of $\ell$ letters.

Comment: Even assuming the sequence is such that it won't overlap with itself, this still double counts, right? For instance, the string that is two copies of the desired text, back to back, will be counted twice.

Comment: Exactly. But also if the string is 1111, then the string 111111 is counted three times for example.